# Configuring Visual Studio Custom Build Tool properties from Premake5

Tags: visual-studio, premake, custom-build

In the project I'm working on, I need to process certain filetypes with a custom command (building assemblies, namely, due to certain plugin / toolchain limitations, which are beside the point). This is configured from our premake script:

```
filter { "files:*.extension" }
    buildcommands("blah.exe %(FullPath) --my --args")
    buildoutputs("$(OutDir)%(FileName).obj")
```

The project will fail to build unless I set the **Properties -> Custom Build Tool -> Link Objects** property to **No** for each individual *.extension item. (These should not be linked *as part of the custom step* anyway.)

How can I configure this particular property from our premake script without resorting to hacks? (e.g. Anything similar to xcodebuildsettings)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a more recent master of premake supports a `linkObjects` file configuration function that does just that (not yet in the [docs](https://github.com/premake/premake-core/wiki/Custom-Build-Commands)). Up we date...

Until then, one possible hack is to use `buildmessage("false")` then do a find-replace all in the generated project files for the Message XML tag to LinkObjects.